# Reading ini file using boost::property_tree not working with children of form A.x

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a file of the following format that I am trying to use boost::property_tree::read_ini and boost::property_tree to parse.

Sample config file (some value contain white space)

```
[Config] 
A = 1000 
B.x = Test 
B.y = Test By 
C.x.y = Test_Cxy 
C.x.z = Test Cxz
[Config2]
...
```

Sample Code

```
 boost::property_tree::ptree config;
 boost::property_tree::read_ini (name, config);

// Correctly Iterates through and displays correct pairs
 for (ptree::const_iterator it = pt.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;
        print(it->second);
    }

const boost::property_tree::ptree& configTree = config.get_child("Config");


// Correctly gets A
std::string test_ = configTree.get<std::string>("A", "Default");

// Doesn't get B.x
std::string test_ = configTree.get<std::string>("B.x", "Default");
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly get B.x, B.y, etc ?? Is it that B.x is being seen as a child of B? And thus I need to get_child of B?

Answer (score 0):

The property tree is a hierarchical data structure where each node can have an ordered sequence of sub-nodes. In this sense the property tree is more similar to XML than flat ini files. And while it can be initialised from both ini files and XML it represents the internal data all the same, and a query of "x.y.z" has a special meaning of selecting the z child of the y child of x.

It boils down to the `string_path` class of the property tree which has the default separator of `.`,

```
/// Default path class. A path is a sequence of values. Groups of values
/// are separated by the separator value, which defaults to '.' cast to
/// the sequence's value type. The group of values is then passed to the
/// translator to get a key.
```

Overall, either avoid dots in the names of your items when you use an ini file, or change the separator by constructing paths explicitly:

```
configTree.get<std::string>(ptree::path("B.x", '/')); // using non-default separator
```